# Real-time js across different computers

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, websocket, real-time

I am making a game to that needs real-time synchronization across mobile and non-mobile devices.  The use case is this, there will be 1-3 people that are using their mobile phone to move their character around on each of their mobile phone screens.  Then there will be a desktop screen that will show how everyone is moving their character.

It only needs to be one way synchronized, in the sense that the mobile phone only needs to update the main screen with the new position.  The main screen never has to communicate with the phone.  I would like to be able to do this in javascript.  Also, I am using Django for the server.

Are there any libraries or preexisting tools to help do this?

Comment: Have you tried Googling it? This seems like something that's too common not to be already solved. I immediately found http://blog.jupo.org/2011/08/13/real-time-web-apps-with-django-and-websockets/ Does this helps you?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the kind of thing [Meteor](http://meteor.com/) is meant for.